# ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector dynamically select template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contenttemplateselector

I set a ContentControl in the right of Window, and set Content binding Items (it's type is ObservableCollection). Now I want to achieve it: if there are no item, ContentControl select first DataTemplate,  and add a item into items, ContentControl will select second DataTemplate to display some info.

Like this:

[image]

The problem is when I add one item into items, ContentControl didnot update and change DataTemplate, I have a try to set mode, UpdateSourceTrigger, etc., but failed. In ViewModel, after delete a item, I use this statements, it will work well **<1>**:

```
private void ExecuteDeleteClientCommand()
{
    ...
    if (DeleteClient(item))
    {
        ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> tmp = TabItems;
        TabItems = null;
        TabItems = tmp;
    }
}
```

.

```
<ContentControl 
    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}" 
    Content="{Binding Items}"/>
```

.

```
public class SingleClientDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
        DependencyObject container)
    {
        ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> obj = 
            item as ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>;
        if (null == obj || 0 == obj.Count)
        {
            return App.Current.FindResource("NullItemDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        return App.Current.FindResource("DefaultDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

**Edited:**
use this way is also failed after delete one item:

```
RaisePropertyChanging(ItemsPropertyName);
RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsPropertyName);
```

but I wonder why it work well with **<1>**.

**Edited2**
It's the delcaration:

```
public const string ItemsPropertyName = "Items";
private ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> items = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();
public ObservableCollection<SingleClientDetailViewModel> TabItems
{
    get { return items; }
    set 
    { 
        if (items == value) { return;}
        RaisePropertyChanging(ItemsPropertyName);
    items = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the 'INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your view model and for the `Items` property?

Comment: I use mvvmlight. The class MyViewModel inherits from ViewModelBase. ViewModelBase : ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ContentControl` will listen only for `PropertyChanged` events and not for `CollectionChanged` event. You'll need to use either an `ItemsControl` or any of its other versions like `ListView` for this behavior.

As a workaround, you can create a `Style` for the `ContentControl` and instead of `TemplateSelector`, define a `DataTrigger` on `Items.Count` and set the `ContentTemplate` accordingly. 
Something like,

```
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Items}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NullItemDataTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NullItemDataTemplate}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, this way work well. But I still dont know why it dont work when I manually call `RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsPropertyName)` in this case: Now Items.Count is 1, and I delete the only one item and call RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsPropertyName).

Comment: Are you sure value of `ItemsPropertyName` is the `string` value `Items` and not null. You didn't provide the property declaration for that property, so cannot comment on that further.

Comment: @SubmarineX Check the capitalization of first letter.